# remote connection to SQL Server 2008 R2 failed from another country?

Tags: sql, remote, connection

I am getting this error message when I try to connect SQL Server 2008 R2 Server Instance

Conditions : 
On the server side : Sql Server Network Configuration : TCP/IP enabled 
                     Sql Server Browser running
                     Windows Firewall is off

My friend can connect the same server from his home but I cannot. Only difference between us is he is in the same country with server...

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to 85.99.115.76\S08.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 0):

What are you connecting with? For SQL Management, you need ports TCP 1433, 1434, 1444, and UDP 1444. If anything is blocking them, it will fail. It could be somewhere on the route that it gets blocked.